# C++/Win32 - How to Iterate specific process's thread list and resolve start address to module?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Please bear in mind that im complete newbie in system programming.

Im trying to do is getting specific process's thread list(Including system process, aka PID 4), and get each thread's PID with Module Name.

ProcessExplorer does this, but im completely clueless that how they does this :(

[image: example]

Any helps, Especially with Code would be appreciated.

I am getting PID by using EnumProcesses (Name to PID)
But clueless by how to implement two other required functions.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Can you point out where to read?

Comment: There's online documentation for all win32 functions.

Comment: So what function are we talking about, to be exact?

Comment: You'll have to figure it out by reading the documentation, but I do suspect it's the same one you're using for the process.

Comment: Are you implying that, i should try searching from whole documentation related with Thread in MSDN? because, thats confusing since i searched MSDN several hours for resolving Thread start address with Module name like that screenshot i posted, there was none.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196770/discussion-between-iharob-al-asimi-and-).

Comment: Checked and sent replies.

Comment: Process explorer is clearly reading the call stack (probably from the bottom up) and hoping it's valid. If somebody knows enough about win32 call stacks they can actually answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot speak for ProcessExplorer, but ProcessHacker does a similar thing and I've looked through its source code a couple times.

They approach is simple in theory but requires some effort to implement (resolving the function name can be tricky).

Here's more or less the step by step process:

- Use `NtQueryInformationThread` to query the thread's start address. ([Code here](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/47074025783a8419405399b6b6cf1d4c86070bc1/phlib/include/phnativeinl.h#L683))
- Find which module that address belongs to and loads its symbol file (pdb)
- Now query that symbol file for the name of the function at that address, if one exists. ([Code here](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/f39a5121b3d6866f987773be8bda38e7ff1bf3ac/ProcessHacker/thrdprv.c#L506)) If there is no function at that address, they just return the module name and the start address in a pretty way (`ModuleName.dll+<startAddress - moduleBase>`)

I hope this clears some things up.

Comment: UC mod owns me and all xD

/ Thank you! :)

Comment: Oh, still i need reference for "Find which module that address belongs to" tho, but guess it also exists in PH?

Comment: @아아니으 that can be done by simply comparing the address with the start address of each module. If it falls within the (moduleBase, moduleBase+moduleSize] range, then you found which module it resides in.

Answer (score 0):

I remember system process(PID is 4) normal user can't access(even administrator).
If you really want analyze system process's info, you need learn something about Windows Kernel Application.

Way to analyze theads in process, the answers of others have been said very clearly.

Comment: You cant inspect its stack but you can still get thread list and suspend/resume them in usermode. checked with driverless PH.